# Configure SSLContext for Spring DiscoveryClient

Tags: java, spring, ssl, netflix-eureka

I am using a Spring `OAuth2RestTemplate` to access a REST service.
I need to change my code use Eureka for service discovery.
All communication must be `HTTPS` and I have a `truststore` on the client side, which contains the certificates to verify server certificates of REST service, `OAuth Server` and `Eureka server`. I am NOT using the `JDK truststore`.

For REST service and the `OAuth` server access I managed to provide a `ClientHttpRequestFactory` which handles `SSL` and uses the certificates from my local `truststore` for `certchain` validation as follows:

```
@Bean
public ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory(final KeyStore trustStore)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException,
                KeyManagementException {
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory
            = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                    SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(
                            trustStore,
                            (x509Certificates, s) -> false).build(),
                    NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);

    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory)
            .build();

    return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
}

@LoadBalanced
@Bean
public OAuth2RestTemplate oauth2RestTemplate(
        final ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory) {
    ClientCredentialsResourceDetails resourceDetails = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();

    resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri(env.getProperty(ACCESS_TOKEN_URI_PROPERTY));

    resourceDetails.setClientId(env.getProperty(CLIENT_ID_PROPERTY));
    resourceDetails.setClientSecret(env.getProperty(CLIENT_SECRET_PROPERTY));
    resourceDetails.setGrantType(env.getProperty(CLIENT_GRANTTYPE_PROPERTY));

    OAuth2RestTemplate result = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails);

    result.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);

    ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider accessTokenProvider = new ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider();
    accessTokenProvider.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);

    result.setAccessTokenProvider(accessTokenProvider);

    return result;
}
```

My configuration is annotated with @EnableDiscoveryClient, so when I @Autowire an OAuth2RestTemplate somewhere in my code, I can use the eureka-name of the service.

Unfortunately the `Eureka` service lookup fails - stating that the certification path cannot be verified.

Can anyone tell me, how to e.g. setup a spring `@Configuration @Bean` which injects my `ClientRequestHttpFactory` into the `jersey client` used by the `spring eureka client`?

I am not allowed to put the certificate chain into the `JDK/JRE` default `truststore`.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that there's more than one place that spring cloud doesn't allow customisation of SSL calls. We got around it by implementing `ApplicationStartingEvent` and using it to load our own truststore from which we create a default SSL context for the running JVM.

The disadvantage is that you don't have any spring support so early on. There are other ways to get in early such as `spring.factories` bootstrap context injection but you may find that the later you hook in the more likely it is that spring cloud will have already tried to connect to Eureka.